# Список регулярный выражений python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, текст

Проверяю никнейм на наличие запрещёных слов обычной проверкой оператором in(запрещённое слово in никнейм)

Нашёл на хабре статью где приведём список регулярных выражений чтобы не заменяли буквы на англиские. Не могу догадатся чтобы in учитовал это тоже. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Прошу пример типа такого: есть к примеру лох с англиской o вместо русской, и чтоб при `if bad_word in nickname` это учитовалось.

Тот самый список выражений:

```
(
  'а' => ['а', 'a', '@'],
  'б' => ['б', '6', 'b'],
  'в' => ['в', 'b', 'v'],
  'г' => ['г', 'r', 'g'],
  'д' => ['д', 'd', 'g'],
  'е' => ['е', 'e'],
  'ё' => ['ё', 'е', 'e'],
  'ж' => ['ж', 'zh', '*'],
  'з' => ['з', '3', 'z'],
  'и' => ['и', 'u', 'i'],
  'й' => ['й', 'u', 'y', 'i'],
  'к' => ['к', 'k', 'i{', '|{'],
  'л' => ['л', 'l', 'ji'],
  'м' => ['м', 'm'],
  'н' => ['н', 'h', 'n'],
  'о' => ['о', 'o', '0'],
  'п' => ['п', 'n', 'p'],
  'р' => ['р', 'r', 'p'],
  'с' => ['с', 'c', 's'],
  'т' => ['т', 'm', 't'],
  'у' => ['у', 'y', 'u'],
  'ф' => ['ф', 'f'],
  'х' => ['х', 'x', 'h', 'к', 'k', '}{'],
  'ц' => ['ц', 'c', 'u,'],
  'ч' => ['ч', 'ch'],
  'ш' => ['ш', 'sh'],
  'щ' => ['щ', 'sch'],
  'ь' => ['ь', 'b'],
  'ы' => ['ы', 'bi'],
  'ъ' => ['ъ'],
  'э' => ['э', 'е', 'e'],
  'ю' => ['ю', 'io'],
  'я' => ['я', 'ya'],
)
```

Comment: а ежели там какой-нить leet будет или перепутаны местами буквы ? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы порекомендовал не заморачиваться с подобным сопоставлением, а использовать старый добрый алгоритм `soundex`. Однако, поскольку его реализация в `jellyfish` с кириллицей работает некорректно, попытайтесь решить свою проблему с помощью модуля `fonetika`:

```
from fonetika.soundex import RussianSoundex

lst = ["корован", "караван", "К0р0ван", "километр", "кoрован"]# в последнем слове
                                                              # первая 'o' - латиница.

soundex = RussianSoundex(delete_first_letter=True)
for i in lst:
    print(soundex.transform(i))
```

получаем кодированные строки:

```
3090208
3090208
3090208
30708049
3O90208
```

Как видите, все коды слов "караван" в разном написании одинаковые

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае можно просто проверять по "белому" списку а-я0-9.

```
import re

def check_name(name):
    return re.match('[а-яА-Я0-9]*', name)

print(check_name('Kонстантин'))
print(check_name('Константин'))
```

Если вы хотите преобразовать имя типа Vasilii в Василий, то возникнут проблемы отличия типа "и" от "й" или "il" это "Л" или "ил".

Comment: Мне кажется, это не то, что требуется. Никнейм может содержать любые символы. Но комбинация этих символов не должна составлять фразу из некого списка. Предположим, что слово `корованы` нельзя использовать. Но люди умные, они могут попытаться ввести `K0p0вaHbI` и т. п. Как избежать замены символов на похожие? Вот в чём, IMHO, заключается вопрос. Ваш же код полностью запрещает все символы, кроме латиницы.

Comment: @nomnoms12, верно

Answer (score 1):

В модуле `fonetika` исправлена работа с латиницей. Теперь все латинские буквы, которые есть в русском алфавите, заменяются кириллицей.

Comment: А какой предыдуший ответ? Но это неважно, т.к. добавлять что-то к уже существующим ответам вы пока  не можете. Вы можете только дать полный и развёрнутый ответ на вопрос ТС.